# SQL group by doesn't work when date in two columns

Tags: sql, group-by, case-when

I have table with 3 columns: agent_id, log_id, date

```
|log_id |agent_id|date                 |
----------------------------------------
|0      |1037    |'2013-05-11 10:26:30'|
|1      |1041    |'2013-05-11 13:01:30'|
|0      |1029    |'2013-05-11 08:22:30'|
|0      |1058    |'2013-05-11 07:04:30'|
|0      |1087    |'2013-05-11 18:54:30'|
|1      |1039    |'2013-05-11 15:21:30'|
|0      |1056    |'2013-05-11 14:28:30'|
|0      |1039    |'2013-05-11 08:12:30'|
```

And now, I'd like to group this result:
When `log_id = 1` then display date in column "logged in" 
when `log_id = 0` then display date in column "logged out"

I wrote sql query

```
select 
agent_id,
CASE WHEN log_id = 0 THEN date
ELSE NULL
END as "logged in",
CASE WHEN log_id = 1 THEN date
ELSE NULL
END as "logged out"
FROM agents
group by agent_id, log_id, date
```

But it is not working as expected.

```
|agent_id|logged_in           |logged_out          |
----------------------------------------------------
1041     |                    | 2013-05-11 13:01:30 
1029     |2013-05-11 08:22:30 |  
1039     |2013-05-11 08:12:30 |  
1058     |2013-05-11 07:04:30 |  
1039     |                    | 2013-05-11 15:21:30 
1056     |2013-05-11 14:28:30 |  
1087     |2013-05-11 18:54:30 |  
1037     |2013-05-11 10:26:30 |
```

For example logged_in and logged_out where agent_id = 1039 should be in one row.

Comment: you should read up on the keyword `left join`

Comment: How are you defining which logged_in and logged_out date to take per agent - If there are multiple dates which one do you want to include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tkank you @fyr it works

```
select 
a.agent_id,
li.date,
lo.date
FROM agents a
LEFT JOIN agents li ON (li.agent_id=a.agent_id and li.log_id = 0)
LEFT JOIN agents lo ON (lo.agent_id=a.agent_id and lo.log_id = 1)
group by a.agent_id, li.date, lo.date
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an aggregate function with your `CASE`. Also don't `GROUP BY` the `log_id` because the values are different, you have a `0` or `1` value which will cause different rows when grouping:

```
select agent_id,
  max(
      CASE 
        WHEN log_id = 0 THEN date
        ELSE NULL
      END) as "logged in",
  max(
      CASE 
        WHEN log_id = 1 THEN date
        ELSE NULL
      END) as "logged out"
FROM agents
group by agent_id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf45d/3)

Then depending on your database, you could further expand this query to `GROUP BY` date, meaning the date without the time included so you could get a login or logout value for each day. Here is a sample query using MySQL:

```
select agent_id,
  date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d') date, 
  max(
      CASE 
        WHEN log_id = 0 THEN date
        ELSE NULL
      END) as "logged in",
  max(
      CASE 
        WHEN log_id = 1 THEN date
        ELSE NULL
      END) as "logged out"
FROM agents
group by agent_id, date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d');
```

See [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c293/1)